# Delphi Chromium Embedded - Clear browser cache

Tags: delphi, browser-cache, chromium-embedded

I am using Delphi Chromium Embedded in my application.
I have the following question: is there a way to clear cache of browser ?

Comment: It seems [`it is not possible`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=293) to do it directly.

Comment: So, the only possibility is to delete cache directory content ?

Comment: It seems so, since there is no way to get pointer and size of the in-memory cache if you'd use it. And since there is no method or access to the in-memory cache, you can only use specific directory and clear its content when you destroy CEF control to manually clear the browser cache. Although there are ways, how to prevent using cache, if that fits to your needs.

Comment: For instance, how can I prevent using cache ? This can be a solution for me.

Comment: You can disable page cache by setting [`Options.coPageCacheDisabled`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/(default)/_cef_browser_settings_t.html#page_cache_disabled) to True, or set [`Options.coApplicationCacheDisabled`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs/projects/(default)/_cef_browser_settings_t.html#application_cache_disabled) to True. But I can't tell you what is the exact difference between them.

Answer (score 1):

I also tried to NOT use the cache, by setting the options right. I set up both options (Page and Application cache) to Disabled, but still, my page was using the cache.
The solution I found was to use

```
chromium1.RecreateBrowser(url);
```

This one cleared my cache.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid using cache: (1) do not set GlobalCEFApp.Cache in your program code and (2) set these two values before calling LoadURL:

```
Chromium1.CustomHeaderName  := 'Cache-Control';
Chromium1.CustomHeaderValue := 'no-cache';
Chromium1.LoadURL(aURL);
```